# Is there way to Update foreign field with only using foreign Id field in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, model, laravel-9

I have 2 related tables.
User and UserCategory table.
And two are associated with category id.

#### User Table Scheme

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('User', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->unique()->comment('User Name');
        $table->foreignId('user_category_id')->constrained('UserCategory');
        $table->string('user_category_name');
        $table->foreign('user_category_name')->references('name')->on('UserCategory');
    });
}
```

#### UserCategory Table Scheme

```php
public function user_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserCategory::class, 'user_category_id');
}
```

#### User Model

```php
public function user_category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserCategory::class, 'user_category_id');
}
```

When I Create or Update `Model`, my ideal is just using `category_id`, then update with `category_name` field like this.

#### My Ideal

```php
\App\Models\User::create([
    'name' => 'Admin User',
    'user_category_id' => 1, // ← not need to specify category_name.
]);
```

Or do I still have to update Like this?

#### In the current

```php
\App\Models\User::create([
    'name' => 'Admin User',
    'user_category_id' => 1,
    'user_category_name' => \App\Model\UserCategory::find(1)->name,// ← I don't want to do this. 
]);
```

Is there a smarter way?

Thank you.

Comment: Please give me reason why do you want user_category_name in your user table ? The purpose of UserCategory table should be to have id, name, slug, ..........etc and in User table : only user_category_id is enough to connect both for create and update, and if you want multiple user categories, then create one more table called "user_categories". Am i wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to store the `user_category_name` in your users table. You can just query it with your users using `User::with('user_category')`, then you can access the category name through the relationship.

If you really want to have the category name in your users table, you can use an observer:

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

Then make a method called `creating`, something like this:

```php
public function creating(User $user) {
    $user->user_category_name = $user->user_category->name;
}
```

And don't forget to register your observer inside your `EventServiceProvider`. With this approach, every time a user is created it will automatically grab the user category name and add it to the record upon insertion.

Comment: Wow Great!
I ditn't know Observer class.
Thank you so much kjoedion!!!